# Differences of Independent Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Take $X,Y$ to be i.i.d random variables. I'm interested in examples when the distribution of $X-Y$ is something "typical." For example, if $X,Y$ are uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$, then $X-Y$ follows a triangular distribution. If $X,Y$ are exponential, then $X-Y$ follows a Laplace distribution. Any other nice examples like this?

Comment: I guess normal, Poisson and exponential should bear this feature. You can try to formalize the idea using a semi group property.

Comment: There is a concept of stable distribution (s.t. sum of linear combination of two variables is distributed as linear function of one of them) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution.